# How do I deal with the edge tile?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I build/dig on the edge tile of a map? My dwarves are walking around the edge of a moat; I assume invaders will too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot dig or build on the edge tile, to prevent you from completely cutting yourself off from the world (for good or ill).  Most people simply dig a most 4-10 tiles in from the edge of the map.

Comment: the issue is the entrance to my fort is against the edge tile. kicking myself for that.

Comment: ... Might want to go back to building a military.

Comment: I think I'm going to seal that entrance with a pair of doors and dig out another entrance. thankfully it's only two tiles wide.

Comment: Why not just flood that one?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You'll have to find another way to block off access. Sounds like you might be able to build a wall up to your moat; get creative!

Comment: blast. I was hoping I was missing something. getting creative...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [DF wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Defense_design#Defending_the_edge), "You're not allowed to wall within five squares of the edge of the map... but this rule has more loopholes than the US federal income tax code."

Some tactics allowed by DF that may apply to this problem:

1) You can build floors all the way to map edge. A floor built over a ramp that is then removed, [removes the ramp](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Ramp#Removing_Ramps). Removing ramps at map edge may stop the ability of foes to path-find into your map.

2) You can smooth un-mined stone and then [fortify](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Fortification) it even if the tile is at the map edge.

3) You can build a [drawbridge at map edge](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Bridge#Improvised_walls). A raised drawbridge acts as a wall. This won't stop flying foes, but it works against normal goblin sieges.